# Which widget is best suited for dynamic tab creation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I need to organize tabs, with the help of which widget and how can I add tabs dynamically? (https://i.ibb.co/k2DJCKq/ex.png)

Required that the title, etc. was different depending on the selected tab.
I thought to use "Tabbed Panel" but did not figure out how to add tabs dynamically. (Pressing the button)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: With `TabbedPanel` you can use `add_widget` to add tabs.